# substitute() with ampersand in replacement

Tags: vimscript, substitute

I’m doing something like this:

`let l:new = substitute(l:old, l:word, l:repl, ‘’)`

`l:repl` comes from an external source and often has an ampersand in it. Is there a way to prevent vim from interpreting the `&` as a `sub-replace-special`? The docs say that with `nomagic`, `&` is just `&`, but I can’t find a way to make `nomagic` apply to the replacement text.

I suppose one way would be to do an additional `substitute()` to replace `&` with `\&`, but that seems… stupid.

Example tests, using `l:old = “Hello friends”`, `l:word = “friends”`, and `l:repl = Alice & Bob`:

- `echo substitute(l:old, l:word, l:repl, ‘’)` → `Hello Alice friends Bob`
- `echo substitute(l:old, ‘\M’.l:word, l:repl, ‘’)` → `Hello Alice friends Bob`
- `echo substitute(l:old, ‘\V’.l:word, l:repl, ‘’)` → `Hello Alice friends Bob`
- `echo substitute(l:old, ‘\V’.l:word, substitute(l:repl, ‘&’, ‘\\&’, ‘’), ‘’)` → `Hello Alice & Bob`

So the last one works but is annoying and involves extra function calls.

I’ve also tried using the ex version, but with the same results.

Comment: You might want to make sure you use straight quotes (`'` and `"`) instead of the curlies :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:h 'magic'` only applies to `:h :s` command. `:h substitute()` function always works as if `:set magic` (and this is for sure written on its help page).

Therefore one must escape his stuff before invoking `substitute()`. The preferred option is

```
:echo substitute(l:old, l:word, escape(l:repl, '&\'), 'g')
```